# Magento - Changing the name of a theme

Tags: magento, themes, magento-1.9

I'm trying to change the name of a theme which I have downloaded recently.

These are the procedures I did.

I have created an `Interface` folder named `x` And a `theme` folder named `y`. Under `app/design/frontend/` and `skin/frontend/` And I moved all contents of the downloaded theme into the theme folder I have created.
Next I have changed the `Current Package Name` name to `x` under `package`.
And the `Default` to `y` under `themes` of `Configurations->Design`

After saving the configurations when I refreshed the store I'm getting only blank page.

Please anyone help me to resolve this issue and setup the theme.

Comment: if you get blank page, change `#ini_set('display_errors', 1);` into `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in order to see the bug. This is in index.php in the root of magento

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are doing well.

**1)** As of you are required to change you magento's current store to new theme. For changing the theme in magento we are having three folder in magento which are as under 
1)app
2)js
3)skin

So your old theme which is there right now will have this 3 folders in it. Now for change of store to new theme all you are required to do is you have to replace this 3 folders by the theme which you want to replace.

Suppose X is theme is there right now and you want to replace it by y. Then you are required to replace app,js and sking of x theme with y.

And then you are required to make some changes in the admin pannel under
->system->configuration->design->theme 
Give appropriate name of the theme which you using right now and then save it. Refresh the front end you theme will be changed.

**2)** Another way to change the theme or you can install the magento theme is you can use the magento connect from
   ->Magento Connect -> Magento Connect Manager -> Get the key of the theme which you want to install ->click on install.

Hope this solutions will be use full to you.